# Sweet little angel of death?

Tags: death-stranding

Higgs: Oh, it’s so hard to form connections when you can’t shake hands… Fortunately, I’ve got a good connection to the other side. Now you? You’re no bridge. But me? I’m bound to all of it-this world, that world, and our sweet little angel of death.

Who is our little sweet angel of death?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely Amelie as per [Journal 21](https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/Journal_21).

> I've got Amelie, fucking finally. She's trapped in Edge Knot City— a horde of BTs all round. She's not going anywhere now. No, I'm gonna go take good care of my sweet little angel of death. My extinction entity. We got plans, me and her...